# Юзер apache не может скопировать файлы по sshfs (php)

Tags: php, apache, centos, sshfs

CentOS7, Есть простой сайт(php 5.4). Внутри вызывается
`exec("cp /1/image.file /tmp/file")`, который не работает, команда
`exec("tail  /1/image.file")` при этом выполняется.

При запуске руками (`sudo -u apache cp/tail`) - работает обе команды.

SSHFS настроен на `allow_other`, `PrivateTmp` в сервисе Apache выставлено в true.

Локальное копирование в tmp - работает. То есть дело именно в копировании по sshfs.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: [privatetmp](https://www.dahelp.ru/zametki/centos-7-privatetmp-directadmin-php-clamd) — вот тут, скорее всего, ваша проблема и зарыта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [офф. документации](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html), `PrivateTmp` указывает systemd создать новый namespace в файловой системе для процесса (apache) и смонтировать туда папки `/tmp` и `/var/tmp`, в следствии чего другие процессы (в том числе sshd) не могут иметь к ним доступа.